# How to start a mysql docker container with a dump.sql file in a single command without using docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker

I need to start a mysql docker container with an initial dump file or create a mysql docker image with initial data.
I don't need to start docker container first and then execute with the dump file in separate commands. I need to run it using a single command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming the data contains your sql dump file:

```
docker run -v "$PWD/data":/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
  --user 1000:1000 \
  --name some-mysql \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw \
  -d \
   mysql:tag
```

ref: [hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)